# How to get access drop-down control from static web method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to get access a drop-down that is in aspx page from static web method but it seems i can't get access and not what am i doing wrong.  I want to set the dropdown index value to -1.  thanks
this is what i am trying to do:

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void Cancel()
    {
     myDDL.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

here is the javascript call

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function Func() {
            //alert("hello!")
            var result = confirm('WARNING');
            if (result) {
                //click ok button
                PageMethods.Delete();
            }
            else {
                //click cancel button
                PageMethods.Cancel();
            }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to get access a drop-down that is in aspx page from static web method

the web method in asp.net page are static, this mean are executed without page context(not completely true, you can access to Session), so what you need its retrieve result from web method, then make your update client side, something like(not tested, sorry):

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'callAJAX.aspx/Cancel',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var result = data.d.result;
            $('#yourDropDownID')[0].selectedIndex = result;

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be myDDL.selectedIndex = -1;

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a control inside webmethod..At the web service method level you cannot see anything about the page structure..
You can try this code for clearing dropdown..

Instead of calling pagemethod Cancel you can clear it inside javascript function itself..

```
 var ddl = document.getElementById('myDDL');
 ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex] = 0;
```

Refer this [link](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/06/aspnet_ajax_invoke_a_static_me.html) for extra reading..

Comment: thanks Jameem, i am getting error at the last line: Error: Object required

Comment: You have to pick the client id of the dropdown by inspecting the element in the browser.Otherwise you cannot access it in javascript,regards..